# Mysql Order , Select highest value item and update to another table

Tags: mysql, update

i have list in data_1 table. i want to select highest value item in one group and update it to another table. can i do that with 1 query?

example : Select "Group B Leader Jane" and update it to other table with coulmns

## Table 1 : data_1

```
id(ai) - group - name - serial - point
52        A      Jhon    A54V     14
53        A      Arthur  B896     11
54        B      Jane    RT3A     14
55        B      Kim     RF31     13
```

### After UPDATE -> Table 2 : data_2

```
id(ai) - name - text1 - text2
8        Jane   RT3A      14
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ... ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1:

```
INSERT INTO data_2 (name, text1, text2)
SELECT name, serial, CAST(point AS varchar(10))
FROM data_1
ORDER BY point DESC
LIMIT 1
```